# Is there any way I can give myself 360° vision in game?

Tags: project-zomboid

A key gameplay mechanic in *Project Zomboid* is that your character can only see what's in front of them, even though the game has an isometric perspective. Anything behind becomes shrouded. That's fine for experienced players, but as a new player, I often find myself overwhelmed by three or four zombies that sneak up on me while I face the opponent in front of me.

I don't want to deal with this additional difficulty of the game while I am still struggling with the controls.

I know that there is a sandbox mode in the game but none of the options I see provide me the enhanced vision I need as I learn to play the game. Is there any way I can achieve this effect?

As a visual aid for this question, I found this image which demonstrates the limited field of view:

[image: limited FOV]

The player is running from a horde, but loses track of the zombies when they turn away. You can see some of the zombies fading from the screen when the player is facing away from them.

I've had characters die because of zombies sneaking behind them and it's unclear if there's a way to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now, and so far in the past there is no way to apply 360° view in the game without mods.

There is a Steam workshop mod though, which might be granting what you are looking for: "NecroForge"

Mandatory disclaimer: Having mods on your game is altering it from the intended gameplay experience. Mods are preferably suggested to only experienced players.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Given the flexibility of the custom sandbox mode and the variety of traits available in the game I was hoping there was some series of options that gave me full vision. Mods it is, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get a 360 vision without mods. Anything you aren't looking at is much darker but at least you can track the zombies without turning your character around.

- On Steam go to properties, general, and add `-debug` to launch options.
- F11 in-game brings up the debug menu.
- In the top left select options.
- Go to cheats, and select "Cheat.Player.SeeEveryone".

Recently picked that up from a post on Reddit.

Makes the game much more visually stable, in my opinion. Takes away some of the panic from not being able to see everything (some might enjoy that) but it's a much better way of playing the game for me. Personally I don't find tunnel vision that fun.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a link to the referenced Reddit post.